# HTTP method for doing all the CRUD operations in a single request

Tags: spring, web-services, http, rest

I'am developing a Spring REST Web service.I just read the uses of all the HTTP methods.

- POST            Creates a new resource.
- GET             Retrieves a resource.
- PUT             Updates an existing resource.
- DELETE          Deletes a resource.

I have a web Service method which does all the CRUD operations.So which HTTP method is best in this case?

Comment: PUT is more like 'replace', PATCH is used to just update a resource. PUT is for PUTting a complete new version.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really the way REST is supposed to work. You should use multiple requests to do multiple things. Unless you really need transactional like behaviour, just do it in multiple requests, it really shouldn't be a problem.

That said, you could PATCH the root resource with the changes you want to make (if you *really* want to do it this way. something like:

```
PATCH /data_objects/

[ { "action":"add",
    "data":<data_for_new_object>
  },
  { "action":"update",
    "data":{
      "id":666,
      "updates":[
        { "key":"age","value":50 },
        { "key":"color","value":"blue"}
      ]
     }
  },
  { "action":"delete",
    "data":{
      "id":69
    }
  }
]
```

This is just one possible way (and probably not that very good) of representing all the changes you want to make in request that you use to modify the root resource.

Answer (score 1):

Don't export a single method to do all CRUD operations.

Declare 4 new methods for CRUD each. Each methods calls original web service method.

Separation can have extra profit, such as caching of GET response and no cacheing for POST/PUT/DELETE.

Comment: I will be calling a web service method from the client side.I have to perform CRUD operations according to the input values for the same method.If I'am declaring 4 new methods for each CRUD ,how will I call those methods from the requested web service method?

Comment: Are all CRUD operations happened in a single request? If yes, use POST method.